# No carga jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

quizas alguien me pueda ayudar,
es que estoy realizando una aplicacion en laravel pero requiero hacer una accion con javascript por ende estoy primero intentando mostrar el valor por consola que rescato de la lista
pero no me muestra nada.

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'controles.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}


      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('control','Control') !!}
        {!! Form::select('idControl',$control,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('accion','Accion') !!}
        {!! Form::select('acciones',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('idRiesgo',$idRiesgo,null,['class'=>'form-control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('idOpcionTratamiento',$idOpcionTratamiento,null,['class'=>'form-control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Registrar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}

      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
      <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#idControl").change(function(){
            var valor = $(this).val();
            console.log(valor):
           // acciones(valor);
            }); 
       });


       /* function  acciones(valor){

          var valor1 = valor;

          $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'{{url('acciones')}}'+'/'+valor1,
            beforeSend: function () {
                      $("#Acciones").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
            success: function(data){
            $('#Acciones').empty().html(data);
            }
          });
        }*/
       /* $(document).ready(function(event){
          $("#idControl").change(function(){
            $.get("acciones/"+event.target.value+"",function(response,state){
              console.log(reponse);
            });
            /* $.get('controlAccion/'+valor, function(data){
                //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
                console.log(data);
                var acciones_select = '<option value="">Seleccione Accion</option>'
                for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
                    acciones_select+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].accion+'</option>';

                      $("#campanas").html(acciones_select);
          });
        });*/
      </script>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: en la consola aparece algún error?

Comment: no, no sale nada, inclusive ya me habia ocurrido una ocasion, pero por arte de magia sirvio jaja

Comment: Qué sucede si colocas los scripts fuera de la etiqueta <body> ?

Comment: Tampoco funciona.

Comment: El la id que llamas con .change() no existe, agregarle la id al selecto o seleccionarlo por el nombre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```js
$(document).on('change','#idControl',function(){
  var valor = $(this).val();
  console.log(valor);
  // acciones(valor);
});
```

```html
<select id="idControl">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
```

[Eventos delegados](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> La delegación de eventos nos permite adjuntar un solo detector de eventos, a un elemento principal, que se activará para todos los descendientes que coincidan con un selector, ya sea que esos descendientes existan ahora o se agreguen en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono de esta forma.